# How to write a function "inOrder" that accepts two callbacks and invokes them in order.

Tags: javascript

How to Implement "inOrder" using the callback pattern and using Promises.

```
var logOne = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("one!");
    }, Math.random() * 1000);

var logTwo = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("two!");
    }, Math.random() * 1000);

inOrder(logOne, logTwo);
```

// one
   // two

// it should always log those two in order regardless of their timing

Comment: `logOne` and `logTwo` are no callbacks, they are return values from `setTimeout`.

Comment: Its impossible to do anything with the timer id ...

Comment: `function inOrder(a, b) { a(); b(); }` does solve the task from your question title, but that doesn't cope with `a` being asynchronous. If you want to wait for an asynchronous result from `a` before invoking `b`, then `a` either has to accept a callback or return a promise.

Answer (score 1):

Its impossible with `setTimeout` directly as you cant do delays etc. But you could create a wrapper that provides a few more options:

```
 function timer(cb, ms) {
   let start = +new Date;
   let timeout = setTimeout(cb, ms);

  return {
    ms,
    stop() {
      if(!timeout) return;
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      ms -= (start - new Date);
      timeout = null;
   },

   start() {
      if(ms > 0 && !timeout) {
        start = +new Date;
        timeout = setTimeout(cb, ms);
      }
   },
   delay(time) {
     this.stop();
     ms += time;
     this.start();
   }
 };
}
```

So now it is quite easy:

```
 function inOrder(a, b) {
   if(a.ms > b.ms)
     b.delay(a.ms - b.ms);
 }
```

Usable as:

```
 const one = timer(() => console.log("one"), 1000);
 const two = timer(() => console.log("two"), 500);

 inOrder(one, two);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create two function `logOne` & `logTwo` and can resolve them using `Promise.resolve`

```js
function logOne() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("one!");
  }, Math.random() * 1000);
}

function logTwo() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("two!");
  }, Math.random() * 5000);
}

function inOrder(a, b) {
  Promise.resolve(a()).then(b())
}
inOrder(logOne, logTwo);
```

Comment: How to do it using callbacks not Promises.

Comment: This is incorrect. Run this a few times and you will get "two! one!". I'll elaborate more in my response.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine has asked me to help him with this one.

So first thing is you won't make it work unless you can use nodejs. In nodejs `setTimeout` returns [Timer](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_class_timeout) object, which (with a little hacky code) you can use to make it work.

Inside browser it's impossible without creating some kind of a wrapper around those functions. @Jonas Wilms has already showed it, so let me show you my hacky implementation:

```
var logOne = setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('one!');
}, 5000);

var logTwo = setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('two!');
}, 0);

function inOrder(logOne, logTwo) {
  var logTwoCallback = logTwo._onTimeout;
  clearTimeout(logTwo);

  setTimeout(function checkTimeout() {
    if (logOne._called) {
      logTwoCallback();
    } else {
      setTimeout(checkTimeout, 0);
    }
  }, 0);
}

inOrder(logOne, logTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var logOne = (callback) =>{
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("one!");
  }, Math.random() * 1000);

  
} 
var logTwo = (callback) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("two!");
  }, Math.random() * 1000);
}

function inOrder(logOne,logTwo){
  setTimeout(() => {
    logOne()
    setTimeout(() => {
      logTwo()
    },1000)
  },0000)
}
inOrder(logOne,logTwo)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).